# Replacing filenames that might vary for specific names on strings

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanted to create a script to automate a process, and succeeded doing it. The thing is, that every time I want to use it I need to replace the filenames in the strings for new ones. I'm sure there is a way to just do it once (maybe using wildcards or so). I am a complete newbie to this whole thing :p

Couldn't figure anything out.

```
move /y "\\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\BASENAME.CHR" "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT"
move /y "\\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\BASENAME.HED" "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT"
move /y "\\enterprise\CP\CLIENT\BASENAME.PRD" "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT"
move /y "\\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\BASENAME.IDX" "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT"
move /y "\\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\BASENAME.INF" "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT"
move /y "\\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\BASENAME.TAD" "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT"

del \\enterprise\TCP\LOG\BASENAME.CHK
copy "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT\BASENAME.HED" "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT\BASENAME.NEW"
```

I'd like to add a string that would replace all the `BASENAME` (the extensions must be the same as above) in all the strings for let's say `ABCD`. That would save me time for changing the filename from `BASENAME` to `ABCD` for each string each time I want to run the script. Any ideas?

Comment: Aaaaaack! OP originally used double-backslash but as the code was not marked as code using `{}`, that double-backslash was rendered by markdown as a single

Comment: @Magoo. yeap :)

Answer (score 1):

```
move /y "\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\%~1.CHR" "\enterprise\PR\CLIENT"
```

and then supply `abcd` to the batch as the first parameter. Execute your batch as

*yourbatchname* abcd

and possibly improve it by using

```
for %%a in (CHR HED PRD IDX inf tad) do move /y "\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\%~1.%%a" "\enterprise\PR\CLIENT"
```

where `%%a` will be substituted by each of the strings in the parentheses and `%1` by the first parameter as above

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I get your question, but you could use variables.

Example:

```
setlocal
set filename=%~1

move /y "\\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\%filename%.CHR" "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT"
...
copy "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT\%filename%.HED" "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT\%filename%.NEW"
```

Then you call your batch file, say myrename.cmd, like so:

```
C:\> myrename.cmd BASENAME
C:\> myrename.cmd ABC
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly you want to move all the `BASENAME.*` files to `ABCD.*` and move them to another folder? You could then just do **myscript.cmd**:

```
ren "\\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\%~1.*" "%~2.*"
move /y \\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\%~2.* "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT\"
del /Q "\\enterprise\TCP\LOG\%~1.CHK"
copy \\enterprise\PR\CLIENT\%~2.HED" "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT\%~2.NEW"
```

then run it like.

```
myscript.cmd BASENAME NEWNAME
```

Which will then take any file called `BASENAME` and rename to `NEWNAME` (where BASENAME and NEWNAME can be anything you input.

Alternatively you can use it to prompt for when double clicking:

```
set /p basename=Enter name to replace:
set /p newname=Enter new name:
ren "\\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\%basename%.*" "%newname%.*"
move /y \\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\%newname%.* "\\enterprise\PR\CLIENT\"
copy \enterprise\PR\CLIENT\%newname%.HED" \\enterprise\PR\CLIENT\%newname%.NEW"
del /Q "\\enterprise\TCP\LOG\%basename%.CHK"
```

Now you can double click the file and it will ask you for for input.

Comment: I will definitely try the double clicking version. However I noticed that the first line (ren "\enterprise\TCP\CLIENT\%basename%.*" "%newname%.*")
will rename BASENAME, that's not quite what I want, I just need to replace BASENAME for the actual name of bases existing in the folder. There is no such file as BASENAME to rename, therefore I might encounter problems. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @JoãoVieira then your question is very unlcear as it seems you want to search anything with a specific basename and rename all instances of it. Please edit and clarify.